# Sygic :the-resource-could-not-be-loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection

Tags: ios, xcode, sygic-mobile-sdk

I have a problem when downloading a map-offline from Sygic Server. Xcode show this error :

```
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://cdn-sygic.*************/in-app-data/maps/********************/******.poi, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://cdn-sygic**************t/in-app-data/maps/********************/******.poi,
```

[image]
I configured perfectly the info.plist to support the download and previously It works fine.

Comment: Can you please show the screenshot for how the info.plist has been configured or share the source file?

Comment: Hi I added a screenshot from my info.plist

Comment: Is it http or https **http://cdn-sygic.xxxxxxxxx **

Comment: ok I resolved the problem by adding arbitrary download property to true !!!!! thank you